# Read data from a Bluetooth scanner in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-bluetooth, barcode-scanner

I am developing an iOS app using Objective C. This app requires an external barcode scanner to scan a barcode and read its data. The name of my scanner is `General Bluetooth HID scanner`. I tried implementing APIs using `CoreBluetooth`. However, `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` does not detect my scanner. However it scans some other bluetooth device called `EST` but not the scanner. The bluetooth is on and the device is also paired. I would appreciate if you could share your valuable answers to this issue.
Below is mycode for scanning peripherals:

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {

    if (central.state != CBManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        return;
    }

    if (central.state == CBManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        // Scan for devices
    [self.myCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];

    }
}
```

Comment: If it is a HID scanner, then it is basically emulating a keyboard.  This is pretty much the worst possible way to try and scan things on iOS as once a  bluetooth keyboard is connected the onscreen keyboard is no longer shown.  HID profile devices cannot be discovered by Core Bluetooth

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Paulw11. Is there any other way i could achieve this?

Comment: If you want to use your existing hardware you need to just use a `UITextField`.  Any other approach would need different hardware that exposes a BLE peripheral that isn't a keyboard.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @Paulw11 ? I am not sure how to handle the same using textfield.

Comment: If the device just appears as a keyboard then all you would do is make a text field active by calling `becomeFirstResponder` and then whatever is scanned would be “typed” into that text field.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It is working. Thanks for you help :)

Comment: @Dyana what scanner are you using? Maybe this scanner has a iOS profile.

Comment: its General Bluetooth HID Barcode Scanner

Comment: bluetooth scanner will act as input for the textfields for all the apps